# Cakephp horizontal checkboxes

Tags: css, cakephp, checkbox

I'm trying to get a list of checkboxes to display across the page instead of vertically
I've read numerous posts in SO and others, and it appears I'm doing the correct thing, but my checkboxes refuse to float horizontally. I've tried a number of solutions including inline styling and assigning a different class in the code. Can someone spot my error please?

**Cake Code**

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('Check.Assessment', array(   'multiple' => 'checkbox')); // checkboxes
?>
```

**Generated HTML**

```
<div class='assessments'>
<div class="input select"><label for="CheckAssessment">Assessment</label><input type="hidden" name="data[Check][Assessment]" value="" id="CheckAssessment"/>

<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Check][Assessment][]" value="1" id="CheckAssessment1" /><label for="CheckAssessment1">Blah</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Check][Assessment][]" value="2" id="CheckAssessment2" /><label for="CheckAssessment2">Blah Blah</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Check][Assessment][]" value="3" id="CheckAssessment3" /><label for="CheckAssessment3">Blah Blah Blah</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Check][Assessment][]" value="4" id="CheckAssessment4" /><label for="CheckAssessment4">Blah Blah Blah Blah</label></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.checkbox
{
float: left;
padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed a nice demo fiddle for you
https://jsfiddle.net/wgrLfxg3/15/

Just fixed the css display:box like this

```
.checkbox
{

padding-right: 15px;
    display:box;
}
```

If you want margin between divs just add

```
padding-bottom:10px
```

or something like this.

If you want them to float left just set

```
left:0;
```

EDIT:

If what you need is to have them inline just add the display:inline-block, here is the demo for this

https://jsfiddle.net/wgrLfxg3/19/

Comment: Thank you. Do I just press run on that page? If so, nothing happens, as the checkboxes are still displayed vertically

Comment: Thank you. The code as above displays the checkboxes horizontally, however they do not display as such in cakephp. It presumably must be due to some other css issue

Comment: Nice to hear it worked for you. Remember to mark the answer as correct so in the future people asking the same on search engines and getting in here can see the solution.